# attempt to index global 'optim' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

```
require 'torch';
require 'nn';
require 'nnx';
mnist = require 'mnist';

fullset = mnist.traindataset()
testset = mnist.testdataset()
trainset = {
    size = 50000,
    data = fullset.data[{{1,50000}}]:double(),
    label = fullset.label[{{1,50000}}]
}
validationset = {
    size = 10000,
    data = fullset.data[{{50001, 60000}}]:double(),
    label = fullset.label[{{50001,60000}}]
}
-- MNIST Dataset has 28x28 images
model = nn.Sequential()

model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(1, 32, 5, 5))         -- 32x24x24
model:add(nn.ReLU())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3, 3, 3, 3))             -- 32x8x8

model:add(nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(32, 64, 5, 5))        -- 64x4x4
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2))             -- 64x2x2
model:add(nn.Reshape(64*2*2))
model:add(nn.Linear(64*2*2, 200))
model:add(nn.Tanh())
model:add(nn.Linear(200, 10))

model:add(nn.LogSoftMax())

criterion = nn.ClassNLLCriterion()

x, dldx = model:getParameters()         -- now x stores the trainable parameters and dldx stores the gradient wrt these params in the model above

sgd_params = {
   learningRate = 1e-2,
   learningRateDecay = 1e-4,
   weightDecay = 1e-3,
   momentum = 1e-4
}

step = function ( batchsize )

    -- setting up variables
    local count = 0
    local current_loss = 0
    local shuffle = torch.randperm(trainset.size)

    -- setting default batchsize as 200
    batchsize = batchsize or 200

    -- setting inputs and targets for minibatches
    for minibatch_number = 1, trainset.size, batchsize do

        local size = math.min( trainset.size - minibatch_number + 1, batchsize )
        local inputs = torch.Tensor(size, 28, 28)
        local targets = torch.Tensor(size)

        for index = 1, size do
            inputs[index] = trainset.data[ shuffle[ index + minibatch_number ]]
            targets[index] = trainset.label[ shuffle[ index + minibatch_number ] ]
        end

        -- defining feval function to return loss and gradients of loss w.r.t. params
        feval = function( x_new )
        --print ( "---------------------------------safe--------------------")

            if x ~= x_new then x:copy(x_new) end

            -- initializing gradParsams to zero
             dldx:zero()

            -- calculating loss and param gradients
            local loss = criterion:forward( model.forward( inputs ), targets )
            model:backward( inputs, criterion:backward( model.output, targets ) )

            return loss, dldx
        end

        -- getting loss
        -- optim returns x*, {fx} where x* is new set of params and {fx} is { loss } => fs[ 1 ]  carries loss from feval

        print(feval ~= nil and x ~= nil and sgd_params ~= nil)
        _,fs = optim.sgd(feval, x, sgd_params)

        count = count + 1
        current_loss = current_loss + fs[ 1 ]
    end

    --returning avg loss over the minibatch
    return current_loss / count        

end

max_iters = 30

for i = 1 ,max_iters do
    local loss = step()
    print(string.format('Epoch: %d Current loss: %4f', i, loss))
end
```

I am new to torch and lua and I'm not able to find an error in the above code. Can anyone suggest a way to debug it?

The error:

```
/home/afroz/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/afroz/test.lua:88: attempt to index global 'optim' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /home/afroz/test.lua:88: in function 'step'
    /home/afroz/test.lua:102: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...froz/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Comment: What you do not understand in `attempt to index global 'optim' (a nil value)`? It means that `optim is nil value` and not table/usedata so you can not use it like `optim.sgd`.

Answer (score 2):

optim is not defined in the scope of your script. You try to call optim.sgd which of course results in the error you see.

Like nn, optim is a extension package to torch.

```
require 'torch';
require 'nn';
require 'nnx';
```

Remember those lines in the beginning of your script? They basically execute the definition of those packages.
Make sure optim is installed, then try to require it.

https://github.com/torch/optim

Answer (score 1):

`optim` is not assigned anywhere in the script, so when the script references `optim.sgd`, its value is `nil` and you get the error you shown. You need to doublecheck the script to make sure the `optim` is assigned the correct value.